# Is there such a thing as filtered LEDs?

Tags: led, light

I'm trying to "re-engineer" (the original designer doesn't manufacture the board anymore but they were kind enough to provide me with the diagram) a circuit that replaces an incandescent bulb with a LED, and it specifies a white LED "filtered" to 3000K. My question is, does somebody out there make a LED with an integrated filter, or do I have to add an external filter to the LED?

EDIT: 
I should have probably said this in the beginning, but the LED is going into a light meter, which is probably why it's filtered down to 3000K. The meter is this one; http://www.jollinger.com/photo/meters/meters/sei_photometer.html

EDIT2:
Now I found the site with the exact thing I'm trying to build, there's definitely a filter on top of that LED. http://www.huwswebthing.talktalk.net/seiled.htm

Comment: LED's don't need filters, they produce color in certain wavelength bands. I think this question could have been answered by reading the wiki on LED's

Comment: What is the light used for! That matters a lot. Even the emissions of stimulated phosphorescence from an LED ("white") are nothing at all like the black body radiation of an incandescent. Spectrum may matter a lot, depending on purpose. What's the purpose?

Comment: There is no such LED that has the same spectrum as incandescent light, yet. Placing a filter over the source would just eliminate some colour, but it cant' add the colour which indeed would be needed to make a LED similar to the bulb.

Comment: CREE has developed a LED, they claim it has 80% of the incandescent bulb spectrum.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I suspect the method used to compute 80% is disingenuous and "sales literature." It may be possible, given enough stimuli and enough different phosphors, to do something. But since I specialize in an area making extensive study and use of phosphors, I'm very suspicious of such a claim. Anything you can point to, of a technical nature, that might help me see spectral details? (I have a nice tome on my working desk here, called "Inorganic Phosphors: Compositions, Preparation and Optical Properties.")

Comment: @jonk I said: "they claim". Those words was intentionally written, to not wrongly understand as: if you buy CREE then you have a LED with 80% spectrum.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes. Got it. But it's a VERY QUESTIONABLE claim. Probably one almost not worthy of being repeated, my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]There are many indicators of light quality which affect the use.

- Intensity, to the eye in (milli)**candela**
- density of light in luminous flux or **lumens** total, for all directions
- Beamwidth in **degrees** to 50% intensity
- x,y color coordinates referencing CIE 1931 standards for which neutral daylight white is 0.310,0.310
- Correlated` Color Temperature (CCT) in degrees Kelvin[K] which is 4500 to 5000'K is preferred daylight and 3000'K is warm with a yellowish tint, while 6000'K is cool with bluish tint
- color rendering index (CRI), which is a value up to 100, where white  LEDs fit between 89 and 92.
- most LEDs use same mix of phosphor but the delicate balance of thin layer determines if 10 - 20% is converted from narrow Blue to broader orange and red by secondary electron phosphor emission.

  - This consumes some of the blue energy to create the longer wavelengths.
  - However to the critical eye there are many subtle shades of offwhite that all have the same CCT of 3000'K due to the broad tolerance of phosphors.

However when I hear a spec that indicates colour filtered, I know the application needs to be reviewed to see if it is an "indicator" or an "illuminator" for some area.

So,which is it , and any idea how it is used?

I have been in business for 11 years specifiying custom LEDs for Autobaun and Swiss Tunnels in a wide variety of applications for Traffic and Emergency lighting.

---

Added
[image]

The luminance of the internal lamp is adjusted using the rheostat (N) until the electrical output of the photoelectric cell (H) matches the calibration mark on the microammeter (A). Turning the base of the instrument drives the two neutral density optical wedges to vary the luminance of the upper diffusion screen (F) image reflected by the mirror spot (C).

Good luck finding a bulb to match the old one. It must be identical in tungsten filament thickness and length and voltage and current vs radiated light.

Comment: Hi, thanks mate! The LED is going into a SEI Photometer as a replacement for the quite special battery and bulb they used around 60 years ago. http://www.jollinger.com/photo/meters/meters/sei_photometer.html

Comment: This instrument allows the eye to compare intensity using a calibrated bulb, battery and micro-ammeter to the distant image spot black or white level.  You could use a warm LED but the Rheostat won't work with an LED for many reasons: calibration, non-linearity.  Much work to reverse engineer the bulb transfer function with light.... does it look like a car bulb?

Comment: It's a small tungsten bulb with a frosted cover, see this site for a picture; http://www.huwswebthing.talktalk.net/seiinstall.htm 
Looks mostly like a frosted flashlight bulb. The circuit would allow for adjusting the output of the LED, so calibrating it shouldn't be a problem, and I do have access to a reference light source.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is just a **misuse of terminology,** and you should read it as merely specifying a white LED with a [color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) of 3000 K.

An incandescent bulb might indeed be filtered to adjust the color of its light, but white LEDs instead use *[phosphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor)* to produce the desired spectrum starting from monochromatic blue light. A filter after that would just be wasteful compared to using the right phosphor mix to start with.

Just buy an LED whose specified color temperature is 3000 K. Or don't, and choose whatever color temperature you like — this affects the light output, not the electrical behavior, and is purely an aesthetic choice unless the produced light is being is used in some precision application  rather than room lighting or as an indicator. The circuit will not care.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, as I couldn't really see the idea with filter. Anyway, see my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a "white LED filtered to 3000K" seems like rather an ignorant suggestion (absent perhaps mitigating facts not in evidence??)  It begs the question, why not simply specify a "3000K" LED and get on with it?  Or have you left out some important detail that would change the picture?

LEDs are so monochromatic that they don't need "filters".  In fact rather the opposite. They are so monochromatic that it either takes multiple (Red/Green/Blue) LEDs to simulate "white" or it takes an ultra-violet LED and a white phosphor (rather the "opposite" of a filter).

Furthermore what exactly do they mean by "white LED"?  You can buy white LEDs in perhaps a dozen different color temperatures (including 3000K).

Comment: See my EDIT, I couldn't understand why you would filter it myself, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information in that description to reproduce that light source.  It is an old design that probably could be significantly improved using modern components (like LEDs with better CRI, etc.)  You should start back at the basic REQUIREMENTS and determine how to generate the required light with modern components.

Comment: If that is simply a local "reference" source for your optical light meter, then it is not clear why the exact color temperature is important here?  It would appear that the BRIGHTNESS of the source is of PRIME IMPORTANCE and the actual color temperature is of almost no consequence.  To be sure you probably need to use a DIFFUSER to ensure a uniformly lit aperture, but it is not clear why the exact color temperature affects the operation of the meter?  It is also not clear how do you calibrate this instrument?  Without accurate calibration it appears to be useless at any color temperature.

Comment: If I've understood the meter correctly, it works by using the users eye to measure the brightness difference between the calibrated light source and the scene, and the user thus twists the meter until they can't discern a brightness difference. So calibrating the meter, for photography purposes, is fairly straight forward; measure a grey card that's evenly lit, expose it and see how off you are. Adjust the brightness of the LED, rinse, lather, repeat. The circuit allows for adjusting the brightness of the LED, so it should be fairly simple.

Comment: That is fine for establishing the Reference Point.  But there is "magic sauce" involved in how bright the reference is vs the position of the adjustment pot.  There does not appear to be any way to calibrate the SLOPE once you have the reference POINT.